# Reading newline char in java

Tags: java, newline, notepad++

I am appending and streaming a bunch of files and I want to trim the header line after the first file. 
On windows the following java code adds a blank line and I see garbled chars in notepad++. Any fixes/suggestions? Thank you.

```
    private int updateHeader(byte[] buffer) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
      if (first) {
        return buffer.length;
      }
      String s, s2;
      s = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
      int k = s.indexOf(System.getProperty("line.separator"), 0);
      s2 = s.substring(k + 1);
      byte[] buffer2 = s2.getBytes("UTF-8");
      System.arraycopy(buffer2, 0, buffer, 0, buffer2.length);
      return buffer2.length;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you should do something like:

```
...
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
int k = s.indexOf(separator, 0);
s2 = s.substring(k + separator.length());
s2 = s2.trim();
...
```

Windows line separators are more than 1 character long (CR + LF) vs. Unix which is LF based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).  Also, this might be tricky if you move files across platforms.

**EDIT** I'm not sure what you're seeing since I don't quite have the files, but you could try trimming the substring as well if you see funky characters.  Are you sure the files are of the right encoding and that you're reading them properly?

Comment: This is better code and it removes the blank line, but I still see garbled chars in notepad++ and the first line from "s2" appears indented in the generated file, Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to copy the first line or the second?  It seems like you are removing up to and including the new line and then copying the remaining into buffer.  Do you mean to only store the first part?

Comment: I mean to discard the first line (as it contains the header) and copy only the data (from line 2). The problem is that line 2 (the new line 1) appears indented in file produced

Comment: **Followup**
<br/>
I used the above Java code on Linux with the separator `"\r\n"` instead of `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to strip the headers and concatenate csv files and it worked ok. (the files were originally generated on Linux with "\r\n")
<br/>

When I tried the same code on Windows with (`"\r\n"` or `System.getProperty("line.separator")`) the first line of the appended file was off and there were some garbled chars. My problem is solved as it is working on Linux. Thanks for the suggestions.